# Adding noise to a dataset to "hide" its distribution

Tags: distributions, references, noise

Given a dataset that follows "some"[1] distribution, how can we add noise to the dataset, such that when the original dataset plus the noise is shown to someone, it looks uniformly random[2]?

*[1]: I understand that this will depend on the distribution that the original dataset follows, but I could not find any related research, not sure what to search for here. Any work related to "hiding" a distribution will do.*

*[2]: The resulting data (original + noise) need not be uniformly random, but it should be such that a third party cannot figure out the original distribution. Ideally we also want to do this by adding minimal noise.*

**More context**: I am working on a cryptography problem where I have a solution that leaks the underlying data distribution. I am trying to get rid of this data leakage. One possible solution could be to add some noise and perform my solution, which would now leak the (original + noise) data distribution, which would prevent the data leakage. Removing / Filtering out the noise in later steps will not be an issue.

In my application it would be best if the resulting signal available to the attacker is computationally indistinguishable from a truly random sample. (This might be hard/impossible... just looking for some related research).

Comment: Could you tell us what the point of this would be?  After all, by converting a dataset into one that is "uniformly random" you are destroying all information about it except for its support (the set of values in it).  Your goals of "adding minimal noise" and "uniformly random" look completely at odds with one another.

Comment: You need to tell us some context for this to be answerable ... so please do that! In his book about stochastic simulation, Brian Ripley tells how he used pseudo-random numbers to generate signal output from submarine sonars. The point being that to the enemy this looked like noise (molding the signal into a spectrum like the ocean background noise spectrum), but the analysts knowing the generated noise could filter it. Is your application something like this?

Comment: @whuber My bad. Added some context. please take a look. I wont be destroying the distribution, just masking it, and making it hard for an adversary to guess the underlying data distribution.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Exactly! Thanks for the reply, added some context... but like you said, I am looking for something similar to what you just mentioned.

Comment: To guarantee the adversary cannot succeed, the signal must be an *iid* sequence.  The only way to do this is to mask the signal with a known *iid* sequence.

Comment: @whuber are there computationally efficient ways to separate a mixture of two signals? The signals are constructed from different iid sequences?